# conda build resolve WARNING not in reqs/run, (i.e. it is overlinking) (likely) or a missing dependency (less likely)

Tags: conda, conda-build

I'm trying to build a conda package for libbytesize but I'm getting errors about mpfr, pcre2, gmp and libc. These dependencies I have defined in both my build dependencies as well as in my run dependencies. Now the package works, I can install it using --use-local and all dependencies get resolved and the package works as expected.
After the build I got numerous "not in reqs/run, (i.e. it is overlinking) (likely) or a missing dependency (less likely)" warnings.
I've spend hours resolving this problem, but apparently unneeded.... Am I correct in assuming all is fine? If so, what does this warning mean?

Thanks!

Regards,
Geert

Comment: Please show the actual output.

Comment: Typically, these should be in `host` dependency, not `build`. Build is for tools like make and compilers. Host is for stuff that is linked against. Run is for what the end-user needs. Also, most compiled libraries have **run_exports**, which means if one lists it in `host`, it will automatically get added to `run` (i.e., one shouldn't manually list them in `run`). Conda-build will use the version used in the `host` environment to define a constraint on compatible versions in the `run`.

Comment: Thanks! Clearly I didn't look into the `host` dependencies yet...
I'll research it tonight.

Comment: Browsing through some Conda Forge recipes is also a great resource. Their maintainer documentation - while nuanced for Conda Forge - is more practically oriented than the generic conda-build documentation.

Comment: Niceone! Thanks for the tip. I'll look into it.